# How do i add specific data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I already know about the insert command     `INSERT INTO database.table (column1) VALUES (entry)`. But I have created a new table in my database `column2` which is empty, How do I add data to the new table without making a new ID in the table. I want to add the new data in column2 next column1's data so it can match up.

Comment: Do you mean you've added a new *column* to the *same table*?  To update existing table records, you're looking for the `UPDATE` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [UPDATE-Command](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp).

Something like

```
UPDATE database.table 
SET column2 = 'what Col2 should be'
```

You can even set a WHERE clause and only update column2 under certain conditions.